# i am trying to setup two routers in my house for longer range

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i have two Huawei routers that i am trying to connect so i have longer range at the house, i set the primary router to 192.168.1.1 and the secondary router to 192.168.1.2 and followed the steps of the tutorial video that i found on YouTube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5QJb3O19zI&t=360s and it still doesn't work just wondering if you guys can help me out 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the first router have DHCP Service running. Make sure it has a internet connection before continuing.

For the second router turn off DHCP Service before connecting to first router. Then connect and allow it to automatically get a IP Address from the first router.

Comment: You may want to add to use the LAN, nor WAN interface on router2, and the same SSID but different non-overlapping frequency as well.

Comment: i tried that and it still doesn't want to work :(

Comment: May I ask which person you are talking too?